# MySQL Workbench - Migration Wizard - invalid option

Tags: mysql-workbench

I encountered following error during "Bulk Data Transfer" stage in MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard:

```
    Starting...
    Prepare information for data copy...
    Prepare information for data copy done
    Determine number of rows to copy....
    Counting number of rows in tables...
    /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/wbcopytables-bin --count-only --passwords-
    from-stdin --odbc-source="DRIVER=PostgreSQL ANSI;SERVER=XX;PORT=XX;DATABASE=XX;UID=XX;UseDeclareFetch=1" --source-timeout= --target-timeout=None --table "XX"

    /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/wbcopytables-bin: Invalid option --source-timeout=


    ERROR: Determine number of rows to copy: Error getting row count from source tables, wbcopytables exited with code 1
    Failed
```

Does anybody have an idea how to handle it?